# Nodejs Crossdomain Issue

Tags: node.js, http, cross-domain

I am trying to connect to a local nodejs server using Unity3D and UniWeb Package. But it keeps telling me :

> Unable to connect, as no valid crossdomain policy was found

[Unity Security Sandbox](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html)

The question is simple: How can I setup a crossdomain policy ? Should I use route or app.use() ?

Is it possible to setup [situation #2](http://entitycrisis.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/uniweb-www-and-crossdomainxml-explained.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to provide a [Socket Policy Server](http://forrst.com/posts/node_js_Flash_Socket_Policy_Server-9vS).

Answer (score 0):

as the documents, crossdomain.xml must be in root.

if you don't use sub-path in url (ex: `example.com/subpath/`) and you use `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` for static files, public directory is mapped to root. so you can put `crossdomain.xml` into `public` directory.

Comment: I use `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));` for static files. And I use a subpath : `http://localhost:3000/api/login`.

Comment: if you use `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));`, `client` diretory is under root and you can access localhost:3000/crossdomain.xml . Can't you?

Comment: Yes i've put the crossdomain.xml in my client folder and I can access it threw `localhost:3000/crossdomain.xml` But Unity keeps telling me `Unable to connect, as no valid crossdomain policy was found`. I am a bit confused.

Comment: Another thing is that I don't see any crossdomain.xml call in my server's log when I call it threw Unity.